# Gelfand trigonometry question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, self-learning

If we start with a lemma that states that when $ a^2+b^2=1$ there exists an angle $ \theta $ such that $ a=\cos\theta $ and $ b=\sin\theta$

Suppose that $\alpha$ is some angle  if $a=4\cos^3\alpha-3\cos\alpha $ and $ b=3\sin\alpha -4\sin^3\alpha $ show that there is an angle $\theta $ such that $ a=\cos\theta $ and $ b=\sin\theta$

Thanks. I think I have to expand and then reduce. But it isn't coming together.  Any suggestions?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation should show you the correct way to use MathJax ;) I'll fix those for you this time.

Comment: Are you sure it's $\alpha$ on both sides of the first equation? I'd expect an $a$ to appear on the LHS like
$$a = 4\cos^3 \alpha - 3\cos \alpha$$

Comment: $cos(3\theta)=4cos^3(\theta)-3cos(\theta), sin(3\theta)=3sin(\theta)-4sin^3(\theta)$

Comment: Yes that was a mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the question

Comment: @frank000: +1, make it an answer ( use $\$\backslash\!\!\cos  \$$ for $\cos $)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with the triple angle formulas

$$a = 4\cos^3\alpha - 3\cos\alpha = \cos(3\alpha)$$

and

$$b = 3\sin\alpha - 4\sin^3\alpha = \sin(3\alpha)$$

then you can take $\theta = 3\alpha$.

If not, you can use the Pythagorean Identity $\sin^2\varphi + \cos^2\varphi = 1$ to simplify the problem.

\begin{align*}
a & = 4\cos^3\alpha - 3\cos\alpha\\
  & = 4\cos\alpha(1 - \sin^2\alpha) - 3\cos\alpha\\
  & = 4\cos\alpha - 4\cos\alpha\sin^2\alpha - 3\cos\alpha\\
  & = \cos\alpha - 4\cos\alpha\sin^2\alpha
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
b & = 3\sin\alpha - 4\sin^3\alpha\\
  & = 3\sin\alpha - 4\sin\alpha(1 - \cos^2\alpha)\\
  & = 3\sin\alpha - 4\sin\alpha + 4\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha\\
  & = -\sin\alpha + 4\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha
\end{align*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 & = (4\cos^3\alpha - 3\cos\alpha)^2 + (3\sin\alpha - 4\sin\alpha)^2\\
          & = (\cos\alpha - 4\cos\alpha\sin^2\alpha)^2 + (-\sin\alpha + 4\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha)^2\\
          & = \cos^2\alpha - 8\cos^2\sin^2\alpha + 16\cos^2\sin^4\alpha + \sin^2\alpha - 8\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha + 16\cos^4\alpha\sin^2\alpha\\
          & = 1 - 16\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\alpha + 16\cos^2\alpha\sin^4\alpha + 16\sin^2\alpha\cos^4\alpha\\
          & = 1 + 16\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\alpha(-1 + \sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha)\\
          & = 1 + 16\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\alpha(-1 + 1)\\
          & = 1 + 0\\
          & = 1
\end{align*}

Hence, by the theorem in the text by Gelfand and Saul, there exists $\theta$ such that $a = \cos\theta$ and $b = \sin\theta$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you get from 1-16cos^2alpha×sin^2alpha+16cos^2alpha×sin^4alpha+16sin^2alpha×cos^4alpha to 1+16cos^2alpha ×sin^2alpha (-1+sin^2alpha+cos^2alpha)?

Comment: I extracted the common factor $16\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\alpha$ from each term.  Clearly, $-16\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\alpha = 16\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\alpha(-1)$.  Observe that $$16\sin^4\alpha\cos^2\alpha = 16\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\alpha(\sin^2\alpha)$$ and that $$16\cos^4\alpha\sin^4\alpha = 16\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\alpha(\cos^2\alpha)$$

Answer (score 1):

should be easy (edit: not really :-)
$$
(4c^3-3c)^2+(3s-4s^3)=
16c^6-24c^4+9c^2+9s^2-24s^4+16s^6=?
$$
and collect powers
$$
16c^6+16s^6-24c^4-24s^4+9c^2+9s^2=16(c^6+s^6)-24(c^4+s^4)+9(c^2+s^2)
$$
Now $9(c^2+s^2)=1$ and the other terms give you $-8$
$$
24=24\cdot 1=24 (c^2+s^2)^2=24(c^4+2s^2c^2+s^4)=24(c^4+s^4)+48s^2c^2
$$
and
$$
16=16\cdot 1=16 (c^2+s^2)^3=16(c^6+3c^4s^2+3c^2s^4+s^6)=16(c^6+s^6)+48c^4s^2+48c^2s^4
=16(c^6+s^6)+48c^2s^2(c^2+s^2)
$$
which is
$$
=16(c^6+s^6)+48c^2s^2
$$
Now subtract!

Comment: I have expanded as you did. I don't understand how you went from the expansion to 16-24+9. How are you doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was totally wrong. I thought for a moment that $c^6+s^6=1$...